# Avoid Blank Pages Numering Openright

Tags: pdftex, books, blank-page

I have to use *book* class, with *openright* option. But i need to avoid numering in blank pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
\include{Dedica}
\include{Ringraziamenti}

\mainmatter
\include{Capitolo1}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use *emptypage* *package* but it just avoid to print the index, but the number is still incremented.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you do not want the numbers incremented? This isn't good. A right hand page has an odd number by definition. Always. At any time. Your page layout depends on it.

Comment: Option `pdftex` isn't doing anything good as an option to basically anything, package `subfigure` is obsolete, package `hyperref` should be loaded last (in most cases).

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for the help. But if i want try to avoid numering is there a way?

Comment: you can try this `\makeatletter
\let\oldcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{%
\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\oldcleardoublepage}}
\makeatother`.

Comment: It does not compile because it says this _File ended while scanning use of \@argdef._